# T-SQL rollback if transformation fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We're integrating our ERP and CRM. Both are third-party applications for which we do not have access to change. We have about 20 tables to synchronize. We are using a transaction. If some of our transformations fail we want to rollback and write an error to our log table. The code is over 4000 lines so far, posted on pastebin, https://pastebin.com/1XWf1cqy. One example is listed below for Marital Status. If the code for marital status does not match any conditions then we want to rollback and write error in our log table. Do we write the rollback command in the else statement or do we need to nest the whole thing in a try catch?

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
--UMARSTAT, 
case PC.UMARSTAT --nvarchar(4) map is wrong
   when 'D' then 'DVRC'
   when 'M' then 'MARR'
   when 'O' then 'UNKN'
   when 'S' then 'SNGL'
   when 'U' then 'UNKN'
   when 'W' then 'WDWD'
   when 'X' then 'S'
   else -- we want to rollback and write error in our log table.
end as marital_status, --PC
```

Comment: Use try-catch and rollback there. Have a look: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/handling-errors-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: You're integrating 20 tables between two separate applications using a single transaction? Why tho?

Comment: This integration is from the CRM so it's the contact record. We're posting it to  the ERP. If the record is not complete it must fail and write an error in our log table so that the CRM administrator can complete the record and initiate the integration again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by when a transformation "fails".

If it fails in a way that generates an error, then you would need to rollback in a try-catch block.

But in your example code, "fails" just means a certain condition wasn't met, but no error is raised.   In that case, the ELSE is the correct place to either do the rollback, or explicitly RAISE an error, that will cause a rollback in the try-catch block.   The code example in your question would not result in an error, so any rollback in the `catch` block would not be executed.

Comment: For other errors we used  (line 3117)
-- Check logs to raise rollback if need
 IF(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @LogErrors) > 0
 RAISERROR ('Error raised in TRY block.', -- Message text.  
               16, -- Severity.  
               1 -- State.  
               );
Those errors are duplicate keys or insert fail for some reason. Does it make sense to use the same method? So just add a error row to the logerrors?